# How to migrate the Nevercode build from one app to another on Hockeyapp?

Tags: android, ios, hockeyapp

I've two apps in hockeyapp dashboard. One is the old version and second new.
After build on Nevercode service the SDS mobile (second on screenshot) get update.

My question is, how to migrate the build from SDS mobile app to app-msds app.
Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/en0euk

Can someone advice?

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs because Nevercode does not have a way to explicitly specify which app on HockeyApp the uploaded bundle should be assigned to.

This way, HockeyApp tries to match the uploaded bundle to an existing app on HockeyApp by the package name or bundle identifier. I'm suspecting that both `SDS Mobile` and `app-msds` are configured with the same bundle identifier on HockeyApp and therefore the app the uploaded build is assigned to is kind of "random".

There are two possible solutions to this problem:

1. Ask Nevercode for a way to specify the HockeyApp "App ID" to which the uploaded build should be assigned to in their configuration: https://developer.nevercode.io/docs/hockeyapp-ios-android
2. Change the bundle identifier of the `SDS Mobile` app on HockeyApp so it doesn't match the uploaded build anymore. See below screenshot for how to do that.

[image]